# SQL Performance: comparing n values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

Let's suppose we want to retrieve `n` elements (type `string`/`varchar(64)`) from a table.

We suppose 0 <= `n` < 1000.

Which of those 2 is the fastest and require the less resources ?

```
SELECT id, last_name 
FROM Users 
WHERE last_name="a" 
OR last_name="b" 
OR last_name="c" 
OR last_name="d"....
```

vs

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM mytable
```

Then a code treatment for filtering on the output, for example in simple Python:

```
result = []
for last_name in output:
    if last_name in POSSIBLE_NAMES:
        result.append(last_name)
```

Comment: If you have an index on `last_name`, that would certainly be faster.  There's no need to return everything in the table, and then iterating over that result in another piece of code.  Also, you should look into `IN ()` instead of listing all of the `OR` statements.

Comment: From my experience I can say that almost everything is faster if it's in database than processing data loaded from database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not sure about comparing all those values in the `WHERE` part of the query!

Comment: Can you use IN, if you can do it by only SQL it would be the best and fastest always. Are your values in memory or another table? Think sets theory and IN that is what RDBS engines are good at ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first should be the fastest.  Filtering *in the database* is the best route to go -- I cannot think of any exceptions off-hand.

The code should be written as:

```
SELECT id, last_name
FROM Users
WHERE last_name IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', . . . );
```

(If you want `first_name` too, then put that in the `SELECT`.)

Single quotes are the ANSI-standard for string constants and `IN` is shorter (and better performing!) than a bunch of `OR` expressions.

Why is this better?

1. Less data is returned from the database to the application.  This is the number one reason.
2. The database can use an index to find the rows, if one is available.
3. MySQL optimizes `IN` with a list of constants by doing a boolean search.
4. Many databases (but not MySQL) can do the comparisons in parallel.

Comment: #2:  It _may_ use an index.  Or it may decide that scanning that able is faster.  #3:  What is a "boolean search"?  Maybe you meant "binary search"?  If so, it would be in the `IN` list, not in the table.